# Make VS jump to line x in editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-sdk, checkin-policy

Im writing a policy plugin for VS which checks several issues with the code. If an issue occurs it will be displayed in the policy warnings tab. Now I want to jump to the line where the issue occurs in the editor when I double click it in the policy warning tab. How can I do that?

```
namespace PolicyPlugin
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyPolicyPlugin : PolicyBase
    {
        //...

        //called if the user clicks on a policy warning
        public override void Activate(PolicyFailure failure)
        {
            // make jump to line x
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get [DTE automation object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx) first:

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
```

or use [alternative ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx) to get it.

An then execute standard command (that's what happens when you press CTRL+G in Visual Studio)

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Goto", "1234")
```

Note: I'm not sure about exact [ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.executecommand.aspx) method signature. Also you can manipulate IDE the same way for [other commands](http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/entryid/1550/Visual-Studio-Macros-Where-to-find-the-full-list-of-commands-available-for-DTE-ExecuteCommand.aspx).

Comment: There are also commands for opening a file, which is the precondition for jumping to a line: ````Edit.OpenFile```` and ````File.OpenFile````. Make sure to wrap the file path in double quotes to escape whitespace: ````dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.OpenFile", $"\"{filePath}\"");````